# How to load and read .txt files as a list instead of individual string variables?

Tags: python

I have a folder of .txt files that I need to work with in python while maintaining each files contents as separate from the others.

so instead of

```
text_1 = "The text of one file"
```

i  want to have

```
all_text= ["The text of one file", "The text of one file", "The text of one file"]
```

the files are loading in the order I want them, I just don't know how to load them as individual from each other

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort has been put in by OP to solve this themselves.

Comment: Use `file.read()` to get the file contents, and append that to your `all_text` list.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python file input", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of files you want to read, this should do it

```
all_text = []
for f_name in files_to_read:
    with open(f_name , 'r') as f:
        all_text.append(f.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import os
dir = YOUR_DIR
files = os.listdir(dir)
all_text = []
for file in files:
    with open(dir+file) as file_object:
        contents = file_object.read()
        all_text.append(contents)
```

Comment: Nice adding the directory list from os

Comment: `all_text = [path.read_text() for path in pathlib.Path(YOUR_DIR).iterdir()]`

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop:

```
files = [list of files]
files_data = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        files_data.append(f.read())
```

this will return an array in which each file is a separate element.

hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for misreading the question before.